# Output voltage\current of 555

Tags: datasheet, 555

Im trying to understand what is the output voltage\current (pin 3) of [that](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf?ts=1610972245698&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fstore%252Fti%252Fen%252Fp%252Fproduct%252F%253Fp%253DNE555DR) `555`.

[image]

If I get it right, when low (logic 0) AND Vcc is 5v AND output current is 8mA, the output voltage is 0.4v

And when high (logic 1) AND Vcc is 5v AND output current is -100mA, the output voltage is 3.3v.

So I have 2 questions:

1. why -100mA when high? and not +100mA?
2. In order to get that 100mA, should I connect a load (lets say resistor) to the output, with the value of (3.3v \ 100mA) = 33ohm?

Appreciate the help

Comment: You are only guaranteed to get 2.75V for the high output, not 3.3V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The convention used here is (-) is current SOURCED BY or flowing OUT of the pin.  The (+) is when current is flowing IN to the pin, i.e. it's SINKING current.
2. The 100mA rating is the MAXIMUM that the pin can source.  Generally you will load the pin much less than this.  You should not design your circuit to maximally load a pin in general.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. so basically the output voltage for Vcc of 5v, is 3.3v. the current will be calculated according to the output load and maximum 100mA

Comment: That's correct!

Answer (score 1):

Some ICs are stronger than others, even with the same part number and manufacturer. That is why the output high when the supply is 5V and the load draws 100mA is 2.75V minimum or 3.3V typical and some might even be 4.0V. It uses antique TTL specs.